# Cannot parse url_app CakePHP

Tags: .htaccess, cakephp

I dont know what I have changed but all my URL was broken, and the error show like this:

In web browser: 
`<a href="&lt;? echo $app_url[" app_path'];="" ?="">sources' class="btn btn-xs btn-primary"&gt;LIST</a>`


Another error:

```
Undefined variable: roles [APP\View\Users\view.ctp, line 33]
Code Context
include - APP\View\Users\view.ctp, line 33
View::_evaluate() - CORE\Cake\View\View.php, line 945
View::_render() - CORE\Cake\View\View.php, line 907
View::render() - CORE\Cake\View\View.php, line 471
Controller::render() - CORE\Cake\Controller\Controller.php, line 948
Dispatcher::_invoke() - CORE\Cake\Routing\Dispatcher.php, line 194
Dispatcher::dispatch() - CORE\Cake\Routing\Dispatcher.php, line 162
[main] - APP\webroot\index.php, line 114
```

i'm dying...can someone help me !!!

Comment: can you be more specific? give us your view code and action to see what you have?

Answer (score 1):

It looks like something has changed your PHP tags to HTML entities as `&lt ;?` (no space) would have been changed from

```
<?php
```

WYSIWYG editors will sometimes do this on user input to prevent code injection.